# Apple Script - Mark all files and/or folders within a specific folder as hidden

Tags: macos, terminal, applescript, macos-catalina

I am familiar with the terminal command `chflags hidden [file path]`. **But I would like to know how to apply it to all files and folders *within* a specific folder**. I would like to run this command from within applescript using `do shell script "..."`. How do I do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From [man chflags](https://www.unix.com/man-page/osx/1/chflags/), the -R option will also act upon the entire contents of a directory:

```
chflags -R hidden <file>
```